# List operations

Tags: haskell

I have a function `cc` declared as following (1st parameter is `a` (list) and 2nd parameter is b (list as well), it should return 3rd list:

```
cc :: [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
cc a b = do
```

Example:

```
a = [("aaa", "xxx"), ("bbb", "xxx")]
b = [("xxx", "ccc"), ("xxx", "ddd")]
c should be [("aaa", "ccc"), ("aaa", "ddd"), ("bbb", "ccc"), ("bbb", "ddd")]
```

`c` is composition of `a` and `b` where each `a` pairs second "index" is `b` pairs first "index".
So `a` ("aaa", "xxx") pair's second "index" is "xxx" and its defined as `b` ("xxx", "ccc") first "index". Regarding to that we create(add) this new pair ("aaa", "ccc") to the return list.

Question is how to do that in Haskell? :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is a list comprehension,

```
cc a b = [(u,x) | (u,v) <- a, (w,x) <- b, v == w]
```

we pair up all elements of `a` with all elements of `b` and filter according to the condition, assembling the result from the parts.

Comment: This works great :) Only for case cc [("a", "b"), ("a", "d"), ("a", "e")] [("b", "c"), ("d", "c")] it returns dublicates [("a","c"),("a","c")]. How could we remove dublicates?

Comment: The least code to remove duplicates would be to use `nub` from `Data.List`. Since that only requires an `Eq` instance, its complexity is quadratic, however, if you want something with better complexity and have an `Ord` instance, `import Data.Set` and `Data.Set.toList . Data.Set.fromList` removes duplicates in O(n*log n), but doesn't respect the order of elements in the original list. If you want O(n*log n) with keeping the original order, it's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension to grab all the combinations of pairs from both lists, with a condition that the second element of the first pair equals the first element of the second pair:

```
[(x, z) | (x, y1) <- a, (y2, z) <- b, y1 == y2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Control.Applicative

c = (,) <$> (fst.unzip) a <*> (snd.unzip) b

-- or --

c = liftA2 (,) (fst $ unzip  a) (snd $ unzip b)
```